# Design patterns for Android

Tags: android, design-patterns

I'm working in a new app for Android. Since it is my first time working with it, I don't know how structure it. I'm searching for a nice design pattern to use.

My application will make connections with a WebService and also, will save some information in local.

Which design patterns will be nice for my app?

I saw MVP pattern (Model-view-presenter) but I read it is focused to do tests.

Answer (score 2):

### WebService interface

Basically you have two main routes to achieve a WebService interface.

- You can use the [`WebApps`](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html) way. It is a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) centered approach, in this way it is more remote-driven: you can upgrade the website css/html and make large changes to the layout and content without requiring your users to upgrade your app on the market.
- You can also use the `WebWorkers` way. It is application/android centered. You use Asynchronous threads to fetch data from the website, on success, they call a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in your UI which is responsible for displaying it using a WebView or android widgets (ListViews for example). This is longer to code and (hence) more error prone but you can achieve a much better android integration (using Notifications, background checking, ListView based activities).

### Information persistence

This really depends on how much information you want to store and how much you want it to be shareable the android way.

- The best (and harder) android integration is achieved with a full-blown [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) whose backend storing is delegated to `sqlite`. [`API Demos`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) have nice code samples for this.
- For a fixed number of data persistence, [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is much simpler.
- [This article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is a good tutorial on android data persistence.

### MVP design

MVP is used throughout android framework, this is not a choice really, you have to comply with it whenever you want to use standard widgets ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the application/activity lifecycle very carefully, writing code which properly fits into this life cycle limits the use of certain design patterns a lot: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

And you should really try to fit into this, it really helps to avoid a lot of strange problems :).